# Rails Model Ownership, Belonging, Delegating

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So, I'm further than I was last time. Made a migration to the database but I'm still having problems.

I'm building an app that has one 'master user' through devise. This master user creates records of employees and items that we're tracking. I then want to be able to create 'transaction records' of an 'employee' and an 'item.' So that when I look at a transaction, I see who it was, and what item it was, and I can look at an employee's view and see all associated transactions, as well as see all associated transactions for an item when looking at an item's view.

I have the database built as shown below, but I'm getting errors like:

```
Transaction#description delegated to item.description, but item is nil: #<Transaction     id: 4, status: true, item_id: 12345, employee_id: 1, created_at: "2013-05-22 23:49:09", updated_at: "2013-05-22 23:49:09">
```

I'm just trying to show all the information about the item and the employee that are associated on each transaction record. I don't know what I'm doing wrong, but I thought that delegating, has_many, and belongs_to should be enough. What am I doing wrong? I really appreciate it.

db/schema.rb

```
    ActiveRecord::Schema.define(:version => 20130516162824) do

      create_table "employees", :force => true do |t|
        t.string   "phone"
        t.string   "name"
        t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
        t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false
      end

      create_table "items", :force => true do |t|
        t.string   "description"
        t.string   "assettag"
        t.datetime "created_at",  :null => false
        t.datetime "updated_at",  :null => false
      end

      create_table "transactions", :force => true do |t|
        t.boolean  "status"
        t.integer  "item_id"
        t.integer  "employee_id"
        t.datetime "created_at",  :null => false
        t.datetime "updated_at",  :null => false
      end

      add_index "transactions", ["employee_id"], :name => "index_transactions_on_employee_id"
      add_index "transactions", ["item_id"], :name => "index_transactions_on_item_id"

      create_table "users", :force => true do |t|
        t.string   "email",                  :default => "", :null => false
        t.string   "encrypted_password",     :default => "", :null => false
        t.string   "reset_password_token"
        t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
        t.datetime "remember_created_at"
        t.integer  "sign_in_count",          :default => 0
        t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
        t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
        t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
        t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
        t.datetime "created_at",                             :null => false
        t.datetime "updated_at",                             :null => false
      end

      add_index "users", ["email"], :name => "index_users_on_email", :unique => true
      add_index "users", ["reset_password_token"], :name => "index_users_on_reset_password_token", :unique => true

    end
```

app/models/transaction.rb

```
    class Transaction < ActiveRecord::Base
      attr_accessible :employee_id, :item_id, :status

      belongs_to :employee
      belongs_to :item

      delegate :phone, :name, to: :employee
      delegate :description, :assettag, to: :item
    end
```

app/models/item.rb

```
    class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
      attr_accessible :assettag, :description

      has_many :transactions
    end
```

app/models/employee.rb

```
class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :phone
  has_many :transactions
end
```

app/views/transaction/show.html.erb

```
    <p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

    <p>
      <b>Status:</b>
      <%= @transaction.status %>
    </p>

    <p>
      <b>Item </b>
      <%= @transaction.item_id %>
    </p>

    <p>                                                                             
      <b>Item </b>                                                                  
      <%= @transaction.description %>                                                   
    </p>

    <p>
      <b>Employee</b>
      <%= @transaction.name %>
      </p>

    <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_transaction_path(@transaction) %> |
    <%= link_to 'Back', transactions_path %>
```

Comment: Make sure you have an item with id 12345.

Comment: Oh, I made a stupid mistake. Its assettag is 12345. Stand by.

Answer (score 0):

I had the assettag as 12345, but the item_id is much lower than that. Had them confused. Thank you to CORTEX!